# ¿Cómo se centra el contenido de una view en la layout de MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente código en la layout de mi proyecto

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <title>My asp.net proyect</title>
   Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

   <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>

   </head>

   <body>
         <!--Encabezado-->
         <header>
            <h2>My Proyect</h2>
         </header>

         <!--Menu-->
         <div>
            @Html.Partial("_Menu")
         </div>


         <!--Contenido-->
         <div class="body-content">
            @RenderBody()
         </div> 

   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
   @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
   </body>
</html>
```

La PartialView es un menú vertical y en la view del index sólo tengo:

```
<div>
   <h2>Mi contenido</h2>
</div>
```

Sin embargo al momento de ejecutarlo se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de centrar el div que contiene el `@RenderBody`? intente con css ponerle un `padding-right: 50px;` pero no funciono

Comment: Intentaste ponerle con Css    .body-content{ text-align: center} ?

Comment: sí, pero tampoco funciono

Answer (score 1):

Por defecto, un `div` es un bloque que ocupa el 100% del ancho del contenedor, a no ser que se cambien sus estilos. Eso quiere decir que en el siguiente código:

```
     <!--Menu-->
     <div>
        @Html.Partial("_Menu")
     </div>


     <!--Contenido-->
     <div class="body-content">
        @RenderBody()
     </div>
```

el `div` que contiene el menú ocupará todo el ancho y obligará al `div` que contiene el `body-content` a ir a la siguiente línea, debajo del menú.

Para solucionarlo tienes muchas opciones, una sencilla:

- Añade una clase al `div` que contiene el menú
- Haz que ambos `div` floten
- Define un ancho para los `div` que permita que ambos estén al lado del otro

Por ejemplo:

```
     <!--Menu-->
     <div class="menu-content">
        @Html.Partial("_Menu")
     </div>

     <!--Contenido-->
     <div class="body-content">
        @RenderBody()
     </div>
```

Y de CSS:

```
.menu-content {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
}

.body-content {
    float:left;
    width:80%;
}
```

> Nota: este método puede fallar porque puede que alguno de los `div` tenga márgenes o paddings que hagan que la suma total sea más de 100%. Puede que tengas que jugar un poco con los valores del `width`.

---

Otra posible solución, teniendo en cuenta que incluyes Bootstrap en tu proyecto, quizás te interesaría más añadir una contenedor más de tipo `.row` y utilizar el sistema de grid propio de Bootstrap (`.col-xs-*`, `.col-sm-*`, etc.) para que se encargue de los anchos de las columnas.

Algo como esto:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <!--Menu-->
      <div class="col-xs-3">
         @Html.Partial("_Menu")
      </div>

      <!--Contenido-->
      <div class="col-xs-9">
         @RenderBody()
      </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Lo dicho, hay muchas posibles soluciones dependiendo de cómo quieras seguir.